# Crystal Report using C# and MySQL. Working on design but always failed to login at run time

Tags: c#, mysql, crystal-reports

So first of all.
I am using Windows 8.1 64 bit, Visual Studio 2013 32 bit, and MySQL (installed using xampp) and the latest version of Crystal Report(as of date, which is CRforVS_13_0_10, which is compatible to VS2013)
also mysql-odbc-connector-32bit, I tried using 64 but my database wont show(for more additional info)

Here how it goes.

I am able to connect on my database using ODBC(32bit, cause i cant see it using 64bit driver)

It works perfectly on design and I can also preview the live data using the preview button.

Now, the problem occurs during run time.
when I run my application, and call the report to set the parameter and refresh it, "Database Login" will prompt, and wont accept any credentials.

Here is my code: (which i saw from someone else)

```
crOfficialList.SetParameterValue("listNumber", listInformation[1]);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crOfficialList;

crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

and i ended up having unlimited "database login" prompt.

---

I also tried setting up the ConnectionInfo using the following code:

```
            ReportDocument rdOfficialList = new ReportDocument();
            TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
            TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
            ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
            Tables CrTables;

            rdOfficialList.Load(Application.StartupPath + "/Reports/crOfficialReceipt.rpt");

            crConnectionInfo.ServerName = "localhost";
            //also tried using the name i set on DSN which is localServer, but it didnt work, It will only prompt unlimited "database login".

            crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "myDB";
            crConnectionInfo.UserID = "root";
            crConnectionInfo.Password = "";

            CrTables = rdOfficialList.Database.Tables;
            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
            {
                crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
                crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
                CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
            }

            ParameterFieldDefinitions crParameterFieldDefinitions;
            ParameterFieldDefinition crParameterFieldDefinition;
            ParameterValues crParameterValues = new ParameterValues();
            ParameterDiscreteValue crParameterDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

            crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = listInformation[1];
            crParameterFieldDefinitions = rdOfficialList.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
            crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions["officialReceiptNumber"];
            crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues;

            crParameterValues.Clear();
            crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue);

            crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues);
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rdOfficialList;
            crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

---

In this case, I am getting an error message "Failed to open the connection".
What do you think guys? Thank you.:)

Comment: Is the database that you are using same for both runtime and design time?

Comment: Sorry, the edit button is not working. @aMazing, Thank for your time, I finally figured it out.
Already solved this by passing a connection string instead of creating a DSN.
In the connection string, I've included the driver version.
Here's the connection string:
DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver}; SERVER=myServerName; DATABASE=myDatabase;  UID=myUserId;PASSWORD=password; OPTION=3

For those who might read this in the future, you can configure your report via 
Database Expert->Create New Connection->Enter Connection String.
dont forget to apply your credentials. Thanks.

Comment: Thats good you have solved. Can you paste you comments as the answer for others to know. @destromon. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. Already solved this by passing a connection string instead of creating a DSN.

In the connection string, I've included the driver version

Here's the connection string:

DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver}; SERVER=myServerName; DATABASE=myDatabase; UID=myUserId;PASSWORD=password; OPTION=3

You can configure your report via **Database Expert->Create New Connection->Enter Connection String**. dont forget to apply your credentials. Thanks.